# Line disappears in paint program when mouse releases

Tags: java, swing, line, paint, repaint

Written below in the BasicLinePix class I try to create a program that allows a user to draw lines by holding the shift key down while simultaneously holding the mouse button down and dragging it to the endpoint. The problem is that when the mouse is released then the line disappears. I am trying to get the line to display in the panel, as well as display multiple lines drawn the same way.

My code looks like:

```
    // this method overrides the paint method defined in JFrame
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);


    }


    // Inner class - instances of this class handle action events
    private class EventHandler implements ActionListener, MouseListener,
            MouseMotionListener {

        private Point startPoint = null; // line's start point
        private Point endPoint = null; // line's most recent end point

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
                statusLabel.setText("Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.isShiftDown()) {

                // record starting point for line
                startPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());

                // initialize endPoint
                endPoint = startPoint;
            }

            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
                g.drawString("Hello", e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //repaint the frame and its contents
            //this executes the paint method defined above
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.isShiftDown()) {
                // Implement rubber-band cursor
                Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                g.setXORMode(drawingPanel.getBackground());

                // REDRAW the line that was drawn
                // most recently during this drag
                // XOR mode means that yellow pixels turn black
                // essentially erasing the existing line
                drawLine(g, startPoint, endPoint);

                // Update the end point of the line to current mouse position
                endPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());

                // Draw line to current mouse position
                // XOR mode: yellow pixels become black
                // black pixels, like those from existing lines, temporarily
                // become
                // yellow
                drawLine(g, startPoint, endPoint);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        private void drawLine(Graphics g, Point start, Point end) {
            if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null) {
                int startX = ((Double) start.getX()).intValue();
                int startY = ((Double) start.getY()).intValue();

                int endX = ((Double) end.getX()).intValue();
                int endY = ((Double) end.getY()).intValue();

                g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples that draw Rectangles as you drag the mouse.

Comment: You'll get an small advance if you comment the repaint() call from the mouseReleased method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a `getGraphics()` call on a component to get a component's Graphics. Draw in the `paintComponent(...)` method. You will find this advice many times on this site and in the Graphics tutorials.

The problem is that the Graphics object obtained from calling `getGraphics()` on a component is not a durable Graphics object and will disappear with the next repaint.

Note that 80% of the code you posted is unrelated to your problem and completely unnecessary and distracting.

Edit: note that it looks like your program might benefit from using a BufferedImage, drawing to it, and then displaying the BufferedImage in a JPanel's paintComponent method. If you do go this route, then yes, it is OK to get the *BufferedImage's* Graphics object via `getGraphics()` as long as you dispose of it when you're done with it.

Edit 2: while it is a good idea to remove unrelated code, don't remove so much as to make your code uncompilable and not runnable. Look into instead creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: thank you I will work with that and see how it works out. And I will edit my post to be more relevant.

Comment: +1, its more then many times that you will find this advice on the fourms. We've been giving this advice for the last 10 years that I've been hanging around the forums. Where are people still finding this bad advice?

Comment: Read the edits and taking that into consideration, I think at this point it is in the best interest of myself and everyone else to close this question and research and work with the information everyone has given me. Thank you all very much!